# Can database primary key table sequence values be managed by Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to set the primary key of new records based on business logic, without database tools like sequence numbers and triggers, and independent of existing table data (like selecting a max value.) Initializing a variable and incrementing it or otherwise manipulating for each new record with business logic is fine, but how do I persist the value across application restarts? (If this is an embarrassingly simple operation, please be kind.)

**Edit:** I think I can ask this question better now. Say I convince my DBA to redefine my table so that a column is added for, say, UUID and we make the necessary changes to use the primary key properly. This has not been well received, because even though the database tables could have been defined better, there is great fear around making such major changes. And other reasons. But say we modify the table columns and data.

Now say the column values previously used as the primary key are a five digit number and we must retain this value and present it to the user as what they perceive as a "primary key". Certainly index the column, present the values there as the record ID. They don't have to understand that it isn't the primary key, they just need to perceive it as the way to identify the record. Business requirements indicate the values of this field should be unique, loosely sequential but tolerating gaps in values. It is VERY important to the client that their forms and views show this value as the identifier. I want to manage THAT value with business logic, again, independent of table sequences and triggers. Can it be done? It seems like such a simple thing, but we are dizzy and headachy from chasing illogical trains of thought.

Comment: Its an embarassingly complex operation. You're introducing stuff like potential race conditions if you have multiple threads. What actual requirement does this fullfil? Is it actually worth the complexity / investment compared to other solutions like autoincrementing integers, UUIDs or even compound PKs?

Comment: Even if you where actually doing it in the database *natural keys* come with a huge load of headaches to deal with. "In fact, surrogate keys work well precisely because there is no association between the value and the record. No matter what happens to the business or the entity, the surrogate key remains neutral." https://www.techrepublic.com/article/the-great-primary-key-debate/#:~:text=A%20primary%20key%20uniquely%20identifies,data%20stored%20in%20other%20tables.&text=As%20such%2C%20the%20primary%2Dkey,data%20to%20which%20it's%20assigned.

Comment: I have left out a lot of background information in an attempt to simplify the problem. The root condition we are trying to puzzle out is actually related to replicating my database across 6 servers (Oracle) and my DBA and I are brainstorming possible solutions, even wild ones.

Comment: Probably better to ask the actual question here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle, as I am not sure what database replication has to do with primary key generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The well stated responses to my question has convinced my DBA and myself to abandon the approach of programmatically generating the primary key when inserting a new record through application logic. Thank you for your assistance in determining yes, it can be done, but should not be done.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure of what you are trying to do. Manually adding primary keys to tables seems like a bad idea.

3 thing that you can do are 1) starting your index from a high number like 98765 instead or 0 like this

```
class CreateReports < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
def self.up
    create_table :reports do |t|
       ...
    end
    execute("ALTER TABLE reports AUTO_INCREMENT = 98765;")
end
```

Your number is still going to be sequential, so 98766, 98767, 98768, 98769, and so on.

Option number 2 is to use a UUID

The way that I like to set this is up is like this.

`rails g migration enable_uuid`

```
# config/db/migrate/..._enable_uuid.rb
class EnableUuid < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    enable_extension 'pgcrypto'
  end
end
```

Set UUID as a default Primary key type

```
# config/initializers/generators.rb
Rails.application.config.generators do |g|
  g.orm :active_record, primary_key_type: :uuid
end
```

Now your next migration should look like

`rails g migration CreateReports`

```
# config/db/migrate/create_post_with_uuid.rb
class CreateReports < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :reports, id: :uuid do |t|
       ...
    end
  end
end
```

When you do `Report.first.id` you should see something like this **#“8485ceca-3a85–41e7-b86e-6b6d93dc4e8b”**

Option number 3 is that you can create a table with out a primary key
like this

```
create_table :reports, :id => false do |t|
  t.bigint :id
  ...
end
```

now you would be able to manage your ids yourself.
I would set a model constraint for uniqness

I hope that this helps.

Comment: I'm actually in favor of a reverse timestamp, but this is a very inexperienced shop and the DBA had never heard of it. But thank you for responding, I haven't worked with initialization generators. You may have guessed already, my knowledge base is broad but not very deep in some places.

Comment: The pgcrypto Postgres extension obviously won't work on Oracle. Instead the something like the SYS_GUID function is used together with a VARCHAR column. https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/uuid-9i

Answer (score 1):

This is very much a X&Y question.

In relational databases primary keys are not really intended to identify records externally. Rather primary keys are how your database links tables together.

Your primary keys should be generated in the database, and there [are very compelling arguments for why it should be a *surrogate key*](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/the-great-primary-key-debate/#:%7E:text=A%20primary%20key%20uniquely%20identifies,data%20stored%20in%20other%20tables.&text=As%20such%2C%20the%20primary%2Dkey,data%20to%20which%20it%27s%20assigned) which has is completely independent from the records data. The primary ones are simplicity, neutrality and decoupling from changes to the buisness logic.

Your model can actually have any number of *identifiers* which are just unique columns which can be used to look up records. For example the venerable slug:

```
/posts/vanity-urls-for-idiots
```

In this hypothetical blog application we are looking up the post by a column slug generated from the title:

```
def show
  @post = Post.find_by!(slug: params[:id])
end
```

There really is nothing in Rails besides convention that keeps you from not exposing the primary key externally if you want use another identifier. You may need to define the `#to_param` method in your model to avoid unintentionally exposing them.

You can very well generate any number of identifiers in your application and you can actually use your database to generate sequences if needed or even use completely external identifiers like for example UIDs from OAuth providers.

Comment: Thank you, I am getting closer to what I really want to know with each response. My Rails application data tables were created by migration, by a new Rails developer, who was dutifully following conventions. But now, the application is scaling, and not well. I think you have inspired me by mentioning the use of slugs. I haven't actually used them before, but now that you mention it they seem like the perfect solution. Or at least a really good one!

Comment: I don't really know (or want to know) enough about Oracle to help you with the issues with replication and PKs and thats kind of an issue for DBAs. If you want to have a seperate identifier which contains a sequence I would consider using a sequence in the database so that the database actually constructs the final value. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views002.htm#ADMIN11796

Comment: That will persist the sequence across application restarts (since its not even done by the application) and provides some degree of protection from race conditions which could occur if your application is running on multiple threads. Not completely sure how to integrate that with ActiveRecord - a callback maybe?

Comment: Sequence numbers managed in the database are the problem. They cause problems when replication happens. But slugs! Yes! With your guys' help, I seem to be growing a pair as we speak!